# Blog post updating question

Tags: blog, website

I am doing my web dev course at the moment.
I just finished the HTML training and in the middle of CSS training.

I have a question regarding making a blog web for myself.
If I am choosing making a web from zero.  I will keep updating the content, Do I have to generate a bright new html file and a CSS file, then link them to my index.html.

Is there an approach that I just focus on the content, such as I just write the markdown file and upload them?  I know, there are some blog host solution, but I prefer doing it myself from zero, just like a learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write a new CSS file for every new HTML file, you can use 1 CSS file in all of your HTML files.

You do need to write a new HTML file for every new page you want to have on your website, if you don't want to create new pages dynamically (with NodeJS, PHP etc).